# How to make a ring/hoop flip as a ball passes through it?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I am trying to make something like this:

[image: animation of a ball passing through a hoop]

but the ball doesn't seem to pass through the ring, but rather passes across the ring. How can I fix this issue?

```css
body {
  height: 50em;
}

.ring {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #ffcf82;
  z-index: 9
}

@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes translate {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-370px);
  }
}

.ring {
  animation-name: spinner;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.ball {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #14e78e;
  margin: 100px;
}

.ball {
  animation-name: translate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```html
<div class="ring"></div>
<div class="ball"></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

I would create the ring using two elements (the bottom and the top part) to be able to adjust the z-index of each one differently:

```css
.ring {
  margin-top:80px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.ring:before,
.ring:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:100%;
  border: 10px solid #ffcf82;
  border-radius:50%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.ring:before {
   z-index:-1;
   clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 0 50%);
}
.ring:after {
   z-index:1;
   clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 50%, 0 50%);
}

@keyframes spinner {
  0%,50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes translate {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-300px);
  }
}

.ring:before,
.ring:after{
  animation: spinner infinite alternate 4s;
}

.ball {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #14e78e;
  margin: 60px 80px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  animation: translate 8s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="ring"></div>
<div class="ball"></div>
```

Another idea in case you need better support than `clip-path`. The trick is to play with transparent color:

```css
.ring {
  margin-top:80px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.ring:before,
.ring:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:100%;
  border: 10px solid #ffcf82;
  border-radius:50%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.ring:before {
   z-index:-1;
}
.ring:after {
   z-index:1;
   border-bottom-color:transparent;
   border-right-color:transparent;
}

@keyframes spinner {
  0%,50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes translate {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-310px);
  }
}

.ring:before,
.ring:after{
  animation: spinner infinite alternate 4s;
}

.ball {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #14e78e;
  margin: 60px 80px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  animation: translate 8s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="ring"></div>
<div class="ball"></div>
```

Comment: This is pretty smooth (nice work!) but the flipping animation is a little delayed on the up bounce and a little early on the down bounce :-) So far the most accurate recreation of OP's desired "outcome" gif.

Comment: @TylerH yes, I wasn't really focusing on a perfect recreation but more about showing the "pass through" effect. Will edit later probably ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can try to change z-index of ball inside of animation

```css
body {
  height: 50em;
}

.ring {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #ffcf82;
  z-index: 9
}

@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes translate {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-370px);
    z-index: 10;
  }
}

.ring {
  animation-name: spinner;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.ball {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #14e78e;
  margin: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.ball {
  animation-name: translate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```html
<div class="ring"></div>
<div class="ball"></div>
```

Comment: The z-index is off for the up-bounce of the ball in this implementation, and the ring does a flip and then reverses it for each pass through rather than just doing a flip.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a 3d transform to get automatically this effect.

Rotate the circle in the X axis. Then, there is one part of it that is behind the plane, and another part that is in front of it. The ball is still in the 0 z plane, so it will naturally appear to cross through the circle:

```css
body {
  height: 50em;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.ring {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #ffcf82;
  z-index: 9;
  margin-top: 100px;
      transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(0deg) ;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

@keyframes spinner {
  0%, 30% {
    transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  60%, 100% {
    transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes translate {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-370px);
  }
}

.ring {
  animation-name: spinner;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.ball {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #14e78e;
  margin: 100px;
}

.ball {
  animation-name: translate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```html
<div class="ring"></div>
<div class="ball"></div>
```

Comment: BTW, this animation has a delay in the hoop flipping, and the hoop flips in the same direction each time rather than "away" from the ball based on its direction (e.g. there are some substantive differences between OP's gif and this implementation).